# Logstash won't start- Error: tibrvnativesd.jar was unexpected at this time

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, logstash

I am attempting to install Logstash(6.5.1) via Windows.

A configuration file was made, and I ran the following command on Powershell:

bin/logstash -f logstash.conf

However, I get this error- \Tibco\tibrv\8.4.2\lib\tibrvnativesd.jar was unexpected at this time.

As I'm new to the world of elastic search, I'm having a hard time in diagnosing the root cause of this error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check in your env variable (CLASSPATH)

Comment: If you're on windows, check if you are using the `logstash.bat` to launch logstash.

Comment: I checked the CLASSPATH and the path to the jar file was specified and I am also using logstash.bat  to start Logstash